# Accurately tracking location in outback?

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, geolocation, tracking, hardware-recommendations

I am looking for a way to efficiently track my whereabouts/tracks whilst traveling through the Australian bushland. In the past, I've just recorded my longitudes and latitudes from a basic GPS onto a notebook and plotted dots to roughly estimate my tracks however the accuracy is low and the process time-consuming.

Was there any GPS device or software I could use that could track/record my location and export that as a trail onto a map or as list of coordinates after the work's finished?

Answer (score 3):

Most basic GPS devices have a recording mode that will store a point every so often, so you could try that.  Otherwise it depends how far out of town you go, the local topography and vegetation. I generally have little trouble with smartphone GPS within 2-3 hours drive of a city. Steep terrain and dense canopy cover will interfere, so some cross-checking with a topographical map is advisable.

Further out I've used older model Spot trackers at work - http://www.findmespot.net.au/. They're pretty accurate, although they really chew through batteries when tracking continuously.